# convert C++ code to C#: SendMessageTimeout()

Tags: c#, c++, sendmessage

First of all docu for SendMessageTimeout:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

i have this C++ code and i want to convert it to C#:

```
LRESULT success = SendMessageTimeout(
    HWND_BROADCAST,
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
    0,
    (LPARAM) "Environment",
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
    5000,
    NULL
);
```

What i did in C#:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        uint Msg,
        UIntPtr wParam,
        IntPtr lParam,
        uint fuFlags,
        uint uTimeout,
        out UIntPtr lpdwResult
    );

    SendMessageTimeout(
        (IntPtr)0xFFFFFFFF,    //HWND_BROADCAST
        0x001A,                //WM_SETTINGCHANGE
        (UIntPtr)0,
        (IntPtr)"Environment", // ERROR_1: can't convert string to IntPtr
        0x0002,                // SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG
        5000,
        out UIntPtr.Zero       // ERROR_2: a static readonly field can not be passed ref or out
    );
```

Comment: Look into marshaling the c-string vs Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni + FreeHGlobal.  For the last part, just define a local and pass it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your issues.

1. [HWND_BROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is `0xFFFF` not `0xFFFFFFFF`
2. You will have to allocate memory for the LPARAM value manually using  [Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then free it after the call using [Marshal.FreeHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You must free this memory or it will leak.  Marshal'd memory is not garbage collected.
3. For `lpdwResult` just create an `IntPtr` variable and pass that in.  You can just ignore its value.

The code should be something like this:

```
IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr setting = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Environment");

SendMessageTimeout(
    (IntPtr)0xFFFF,        //HWND_BROADCAST
    0x001A,                //WM_SETTINGCHANGE
    (UIntPtr)0,
    (IntPtr)setting,
    0x0002,                // SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG
    5000,
    out result
);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(setting);
```

In general you need to be careful when freeing memory that you pass to a `SendMessage` call since you don't know what the receving window will do with the pointer that you pass to it.  Howerver since `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` is a built in Windows message, Windows will handle this pointer for you.

Comment: Hi, this prevents me from having to reboot the system to have the changes take effect. But I still need to restart CMD/Powershell. Do you happen to know a way to prevent this too?

Answer (score 5):

SendMessage is a bit painful due to the non-descript argument types it uses.  Necessary because it needs to do many jobs.  Necessary in the C language, but not in C#.  What you want to do here is take advantage of the C# language supporting overloads.  The IntPtr arguments can just be reference type references, the pinvoke marshaller will properly convert them to a pointer and take care of the memory management hassle.  So just craft another one that's compatible with the way you want to use it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    int Msg,
    IntPtr wParam,
    string lParam,
    int fuFlags,
    int uTimeout,
    IntPtr lpdwResult
);
```

Now you can use:

```
 SendMessageTimeout((IntPtr)0xffff, 0x001A, IntPtr.Zero, "Environment", 
                    2, 5000, IntPtr.Zero);
```